# Join distant SQL tables without pulling data in between

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have two mySQL tables that are distantly related: Box and Schedule.

The tables are only related through many other table joins.

A box has a subscription ID, a subscription has a boxContent ID and a boxContent has a Schedule ID.

Many boxes have one subscription
One Subscription has many boxContents
Many boxContents have one Schedule

I need to get all of the Schedule details attached to boxes and group them by the delivery date of the boxes.

The problem I have, is that I cannot figure out how to group them, or join them, so that the subscription and boxcontents data doesnt fill the results up with invalid results.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    Box.expected_delivery_date, count(Box.id) num_boxes
FROM
    Box

WHERE
    Box.state = 3 AND Box.status = 2
GROUP BY Box.expected_delivery_date;
```

returns the correct amount of boxes that I need to look for:

**2010-10-01 - 2 

2010-10-07 - 4**

However, when I include the tables I need to link the two together, I get all of their data confusing the results

```
SELECT 
    Box.expected_delivery_date, count(Box.id) num_boxes
FROM
    Box
        JOIN
    Subscription ON Box.subscription_id = Subscription.id
        JOIN
    BoxContent ON Subscription.id = BoxContent.subscription_id
        JOIN
    Schedule ON Schedule.id = BoxContent.schedule_id
WHERE
    Box.state = 3 AND Box.status = 2
GROUP BY Box.expected_delivery_date;
```

Returns:

**2010-10-01 - 10 

2010-10-07 - 17**

Im sure there is a simple way to do this, Im just not great at SQL.

Comment: Drop the grouping from both queries, and actually look at the rows that they're returning - maybe you'll spot the reason why there's duplicates. Then, instead of joining with the table that's causing the duplicates directly, join with a subselect that gets rid of them beforehand using `DISTINCT` or something like that.

Comment: It's hard to give you more specific advice without actually having the schema you're using, some dummy data to fill it, and examples of the desired and actual output you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` to count the distinct `Box.id` in your query -

```
SELECT 
    Box.expected_delivery_date, count(DISTINCT Box.id) num_boxes
FROM
    Box
        JOIN
    Subscription ON Box.subscription_id = Subscription.id
        JOIN
    BoxContent ON Subscription.id = BoxContent.subscription_id
        JOIN
    Schedule ON Schedule.id = BoxContent.schedule_id
WHERE
    Box.state = 3 AND Box.status = 2
GROUP BY Box.expected_delivery_date;
```

This should return

**2010-10-01 - 2

2010-10-07 - 4**

Similarly, when you `JOIN` box with subscription, content, schedule tables you will get many duplicates. You need to analyze the data and see how you need to `GROUP BY`.

Use this query to see the actual data used by the query before grouping and decide on which columns to group by. Mostly, it will be the columns where you see duplicate data in multiple rows.

```
SELECT 
    Box.expected_delivery_date, Box.id BoxID, Schedule.id SchID
FROM
    Box
        JOIN
    Subscription ON Box.subscription_id = Subscription.id
        JOIN
    BoxContent ON Subscription.id = BoxContent.subscription_id
        JOIN
    Schedule ON Schedule.id = BoxContent.schedule_id
WHERE
    Box.state = 3 AND Box.status = 2
```

You may even try `SELECT Box.*, Schedule.*` in above query to come up with a final grouping.

If you need any more specific answer, you will have to provide the dummy data for all those table and the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the comments and try using `DISTINCT`. This should filter out the duplicate rows you would be getting by joining your "middle" tables.